# Take front/selfie photo if wrong password is input on the lock screen

Tags: security, lock-screens, photos

Operating systems like iOS include the system that when another person tries to unlock your phone without your permission, it takes a photo of that person and warns you.

Is it possible to have this on Android?

Comment: Asking why Android (assuming AOSP, the code base for all Android ROM) doesn't have this feature is rarely fruitful because unless this has been brought up officially, we also don't know why (which makes the question opinion-based). I edited the question to make the question on-topic, feel free to improve it further.